# Prevent System Generated Toast in Android

Tags: android, android-toast, clipboardmanager

I have added a OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() in my service, which detects when user copies any text, and displays some output as Toast.

However in some apps (e.g. Gmail) when user copies the test, a Toast with message "Text copied to clipboard" is displayed which overrides Toast displayed by my message.

How can I suppress the other Toast message?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. There is no mechanism to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You, as a developer, have no means of affecting the toasts displayed by another app.